# Word for having the perfect word for an occasion

Tags: meaning, greek

I remember reading or hearing once that there was a word, I think of Greek etymological roots, that meant "having exactly the right word for an occasion."

It's rather frustrating that I can't remember *this* particular word, so I'm hoping someone else out there knows it!

Comment: The Greeks had a word for it ...

Comment: So the word must be 'being Greek'?

Answer (score 4):

***apropos*** as defined [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=apropos)

> very appropriate to a particular situation.
>
> "the word 'conglomerate' was decidedly apropos"

From [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=a&p=39&allowed_in_frame=0)

> 1660s, "opportunely," from French à propos "to the purpose," from
>   propos "thing said in conversation, talk; purpose, plan," from Latin
>   propositium "purpose," past participle of proponere "to set forth,
>   propose" (see propound). Meaning "as regards" is 1761, from French. As
>   an adjective, "to the point or purpose," from 1690s

Not Greek, but apropos nonetheless.

Comment: Although I am with you, this definitely works, I don't think it's the one I'm remembering. This was something more esoteric, that was with regard particularly to using the correct *word*, not just being well-suited generally :/

Comment: @Elizabeth Maddening, isn't it?  And when it comes to you it will be sooo obvious!

Comment: omg, SO maddening!

Answer (score 2):

***le mot juste***, meaning "the right word", is a nice loan phrase from French which has slipped into English via the French Novelist Flaubert. It means the perfect word for a situation.

Plural would be ***les mots justes***.

It even made its way into Urban Dictionary, here: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=le+mot+juste

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***apposite***

> Being of striking appropriateness and pertinence [WordNet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apposite)